# combining 2 lists in clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to make a new list that is made up of 2 pre-existing lists. Basically, if `a` is a list and `b` is a list, I want to make List `c` which is the elements of `a` followed by the elements of `b`. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for [concat](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.3.0/clojure.core/concat) function:

```
(concat a b)
```

For example:

```
(concat '(1 2) '(2 3 4))
:> (1 2 2 3 4)
```

Comment: FYI - `concat` is lazy, so be careful not to apply it too many times without _forcing_ the sequence with something like [`doall`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doall), otherwise you can get a stack overflow. You'd need to do a _lot_ of concatenations before you'd blow stack, but the laziness can cause other weird behaviors as well (e.g., if you're using `time` to measure the speed of your algorithm, the lazy values might not get forced within the `time` call).

Comment: @DaoWen Do you have a reference for `concat` blowing the stack?

Comment: @MSmith - This example shows the stack overflow caused by laziness in `concat` as well as forcing with `doall` eliminating the problem: https://www.refheap.com/paste/6138

Comment: That is an interesting example.  You are using `recur` to create a stack of deferred calls that will then blow the stack when called.  I generally do not see lazy calls being nested in that way but, as you have shown, it can be done.